# Mongodb connection error ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

When I tried to connect to mangolab, I get Err ECONNRESET

```
var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

var url = "mongodb://username:password@urlForServer:port/databaseName";
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I have put right info in connection url. please help.
[image: ECONNRESET Error]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it was due to corporate network restrictions which could be your case also

Your network may not allow this type of connection to this external address and port

Comment: is it port restriction or web address restriction??

Comment: For me I think it was port or protocol restrictions. I needed to use an wifi connection that was available

Answer (score 0):

For me, option `wtimeoutMS=0` did the trick